# How to Access same name Variable Different Class Variable in Main Method in java

Tags: java, android

> Accessing Same Name Data Members In Main Method Using obj Object not
>   creating object in Class A and Class B.

```
class A {
  int i = 10;
}
class B extends A {
 int i = 20;
}
class C extends B {
  int i = 30;
}
public class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args)   {
    C obj = new C ();
    System.out.println (obj.i);
    //How to access Class A variable
    //How to access Class B Variable
  }
}
```

> Print Class A Variable  Print Class B Variable  Without Creating
>   Object of Class A and Class B.

Comment: make them static ?

Comment: Withoud any changes

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println (((A) obj).i);` and `System.out.println (((B) obj).i);` respectively. **If** they were `protected` fields, they would be inherited. As is, they are hidden (*shadowed*) package-private fields.

Since you've now mentioned that you cannot use a simple cast, the next best option (I can think of) is *reflection*. You can iterate the `Field`(s), find the field named `i`, make it accessible and then print it (and the class name). For example,

```
try {
    Class<?>[] classes = { A.class, B.class, C.class };
    for (Class<?> cls : classes) {
        for (Field f : cls.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (f.getName().equals("i")) {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                System.out.printf("%s %s%n", cls.getSimpleName(), f.get(obj));
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outputs

```
A 10
B 20
C 30
```

Comment: Not creating another class object

Comment: Casting (as here) does not create another instance.

Comment: Casting is not allowed

Comment: What are **all** of the rules? Because casting is the sane way to do it. You need to edit your question to include what is (and is not) allowed.

Comment: Sir In this I have Requierd to access Variable i . withod using TypeCasting and Creating of Object and Not Making Data Member as Static.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Reflection. You can get the super class and get the i value. 
This approach don't use the typeCasting, create object and statie member. I think it will help you.

```
class A {
    int i = 10;
}
class B extends A {
    int i = 20;
}
class C extends B {
    int i = 30;
}
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args)   {
        try {
            C obj = new C();
            System.out.println(obj.i);
            // get the Class B
            Class b = obj.getClass().getSuperclass();
            System.out.println(b.getDeclaredField("i").getInt(obj));
            // get the Class A
            Class a = b.getSuperclass();
            System.out.println(a.getDeclaredField("i").getInt(obj));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }

        // Output
        // 30
        // 20
        // 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Not Use Constructor of class B and A .

Comment: Sir In this I have Requierd to access Variable i . withod using TypeCasting and Creating of Object and Not Making Data Member as Static.

Comment: Bro first of all you compile own code in your compiler it is execuatable or not.

Comment: @AshishShahi I updated the full code. You can copy and past to your IDE or java compiler and run it. It work fine.